# allow redirects with iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

with the following rules, php can't make a `redirect` to another file. it's freezes at the point when it gets to`header("Content-type: video/x-flv");
                header("Location:" . $VIDEO);`
 or could be `get_headers();` on my php script.

my iptables:

```
 iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:22151 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:webcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:http 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

what i've tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

as soon as i remove the `DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere` everything works fine.

Comment: PHP nothing to do with iptables... and iptables does not look at the contents of an http session.  I think you're grasping at things that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP redirects don't use ICMP packets; your problem appears instead to be a missing space in the second `header()` call. Try `header("Location: " . $VIDEO)` instead.

Comment: no, it's working when i remove `iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
`

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: its a fact. as soon as i add the rules i can't play videos, when i drop the rule everything is working.

Comment: or could be it stops at `get_headers();`

Comment: I think I misread your original post; if the videos start working when you remove the DROP rule, then presumably there's something about the post-redirect incoming connection that it can't handle. What exactly does `$VIDEO` contain at the point in your script where it's used in the `header()` call?